# How can I integrate Spring Cloud with logback?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-cloud

I have two Spring Boot applications:

1. `cloud-config`

   It has following file structure:

   ```
   └───src
       └───main
           └───environment
               └───default
                   ├───application.yml
                   └───bootstrap.yml
   ...
   ```

   `application.yml`:

   ```
   server:
     port: 8087

   spring:
     cloud:
       config:
         server:
           git:
             uri: ssh://path-to-repository.git
   ```

   `bootstrap.yml`:

   ```
   spring:
     application:
       name: cloud-config
   ```
2. `main-application`:

   ```
   └───src
       └───main
           └───environment
               └───default
                   ├───bootstrap.yml
                   └───logback.xml
   ```

   I have `application.yml` for my `main-application` in git repository.

Also in git repository I have file with properties: `application-default.properties`.

**I want to move `logback.xml` to git repository to get it with spring-cloud. How can I do this?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve my task I have done following:

1. add `logback.xml` to my Spring Cloud repository;
2. remove `logback.xml` from `main > environment > default` directory;
3. add to `bootstrap.yml` of `main-application` module:

   ```
   logging:
       config: http://localhost:8087/main-application/default/master/logback.xml
   ```

---

- **Documentation**: description of `logging: config:` path: [Serving plain text](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-config.adoc#serving-plain-text)

Comment: this is hack as hell, you have hard wired environment modifiers as well as the server. I wouldn't think it as a solution, just a workaround. It should work seamlessly just like reading up the properties file for an app, I haven't found yet the solution though. I will surely write here a better one if I find it

Comment: This is not a hack. One already specifies the config server URL in bootstrap.yml so having the logging config also point to it is not a hack. The docs cite it as a valid usecase. Even books like Packts Spring Microservices mentions this as a usecase.

Comment: Important note - this won't work if config server requires authentication. Spent almost a day to figure this out - since logging config wasn't retrieved nothing was logged about the error either. Luckily spending time with the debugger saved me.


It is however possible to point logging.config to somewhere in the filesystem (i.e /opt/yourApp/logback.xml) and then springProperty elements will work. This makes it possible to create a base logback.xml and configure it through application properties from cloud config.

Answer (score 1):

```
logging.config=${spring.cloud.config.uri}/guestservices/default/master/logback.xml
```

works for me.