# Can't apply xml-configuration for logback from config server

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-cloud-config

I'm developing an application with springboot which has an microservice architecture.
There is Service A (Port 8080) and spring cloud's config-server (Port 8888), which provides the properties-file for Service A from a Git-Repo (located locally under the ~/git//config).
This works well so far and Service A receive the properties-file from config-server.

For logging i use the **logback** logging framework and created a XML-Configuration file named **logback-spring.xml** with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />

<appender name="Console"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %highlight(%-5level) %black(%d{ISO8601}) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="RollingFile"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/spring-boot-logger.log</file>
    <encoder
        class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</root>

<logger name="com.example" level="trace" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</logger>
```

I want to distribute this configuration file to Service A by the config-server to have a central point to manage this for all future services.
Inside of the git-repo for config i created a directory named **logging** with that file inside. So the local path to that file is: *~/git//config/logging/logback-spring.xml*.

Related to the docs([documentation of config server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_serving_plain_text)) in my case i can retrieve this file with curl *localhost:8888/config/spring/main/logging/logback.xml* and when i curl this i get the content from this file.
[image: result from curl]

But now the problem:
I specified this logging.config - location to this endpoint to let springboot load this XML file as a config client. The application-properties in Service A has following content:
[image: content of properties-file of Service A]
When i start Service A while hoping to get this configuration appended to the logs, i am getting following error:
[image]

How can i properly include the configuration to Service A?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Add config to `bootstrap`, remove logback xml from sources.. !? ;) https://stackoverflow.com/q/42492763/592355 ... And please don't use images for code/stacktraces!

Comment: Thank you @xerx593, you saved my day! This was the solution for me to put this into bootstrap.yml after i included the **spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap**-dependency.
Sorry, i won't post code/errors as images anymore, so people can easily copy the content.